# CakePHP 2.0 send eMail error

Tags: email, cakephp-2.0

I'm using the SignMeUp Plugin for user registration in CakePHP 2.0 (whose homepage seems to be down atm).
For the most part, everything works perfectly fine, except that I'm getting the following seemingly unrelated error whenever a function uses $this->Email->send() :

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 111]

The line is:

```
public function beforeRender($viewFile) {
        $this->options['url'] = array_merge($this->request->params['pass'],
$this->request->params['named']);
```

Not sure how that is actually related to the email, so I'm at a loss as to what can possibly cause this error, as the emails are actually being sent no problem.

An example function in the plugin would be:

```
protected function __sendActivationEmail($userData) {
    $this->__setUpEmailParams($userData);
    $this->__parseEmailSubject('activation', $userData);
    if ($this->__setTemplate(Configure::read('SignMeUp.activation_template'))) {
        if ($this->Email->send()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I personally see nothing wrong with this either... Not sure what else could possibly be causing this error. If someone of you has any kind of idea, that would really be appreciated!

BTW: If I set debug to 0, I get a blank page after the function executes instead of a proper redirect, so that's not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I included the paginator as helper:
public $helpers = array('Time','Paginator');
In CakePHP 2.0 the Paginator is always included and for some reason there seems to be a conflict with the sendMail if you include the helper in the controller. So if you delete the Paginator from the helpers list it should work without error.